# How to combine a Pandas dataframe with a Tensor dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I have a Tensor dataset that is a list of file names and a Pandas dataframe that contains metadata for each file.

```
filename_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(path + "/*.bmp")
metadata_df = pandas.read_csv(path + "/metadata.csv")
```

File names contain an idx that references a line in the metadata dataframe, like "3_data.bmp" where 3 is the idx. I hoped to call `filename_ds.map(combine_data)`.

It appears to be not as simple as parsing the file name and doing a dataframe lookup. The following fails because `filename` is a Tensor, and since I'm running this on a `Dataset.map()` call, I do not have access to `tf.executing_eagerly()` methods like `.numpy()` and cannot get a string value from the filename to do my regex and df lookup.

```
combine_data(filename)
  idx = re.findall("(\d+)_data.bmp", filename)[0]
  val = metadata_df.loc[metadata_df["idx"] == idx]["test-col"]
  ...
```

New to Tensorflow, and I suspect I'm going about this in an odd way. What would be the correct way to go about this? I could list my files and concatenate a dataset for each file, but I'm wondering if I'm just missing the "Tensorflow way" of doing it.

Comment: you can loop using `as_numpy_iterator()` but not sure if you have limitations. something like this can work. `dataset_list=list(filename_ds.as_numpy_iterator())
for each_file in dataset_list:
    
    file_name=each_file.decode('utf-8') # this will contain the abs path /user/me/so/file_1.png
    try:
        idx=re.findall("(\d+).*.png", file_name)[0] # changed for my case
    except :
        print("Exception==>")
    print(f"File:{file_name},idx:{idx}")`

Answer (score 1):

One way of iteration is through `as_numpy_iterator()`

```
dataset_list=list(filename_ds.as_numpy_iterator())
for each_file in dataset_list:
    
    file_name=each_file.decode('utf-8') # this will contain the abs path /user/me/so/file_1.png
    try:
        idx=re.findall("(\d+).*.png", file_name)[0] # changed for my case
    except :
        print("Exception==>")
    print(f"File:{file_name},idx:{idx}")
```